# Using Restlet ClientResource cannot send entity to Restlet Service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, gwt, restlet

I'm having problem with Restlet client call to a working rest service:

```
    final ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(Routes.PUBLIC_STORE_API);
    resource.setOnResponse(new Uniform() {
        public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
            try {
                Status status = response.getStatus();
                if(!Status.isError(status.getCode())){
                    String jsonResponse = response.getEntity().getText();
                } else {
                    // Handle error
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                callback.failure(new Throwable(e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    });
    JsniHelper.consoleLog("Adding object id=" + id + " type=" + type + " data=" + jsonObject);
    resource.getReference().addQueryParameter("type", type);
    resource.getReference().addQueryParameter("id",id);
    resource.post(jsonObject, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

At the point of log above the object is a valid JSON string.

The Restlet `ServerResource` is able to get both the `id` and `type` Strings however the entity is always `null`:

```
@Post("json")
public Representation add(Representation entity){ // omitted }
```

I tried to use CURL and the Rest service was able to process the JSON string properly.

What could be the problem with my code in GWT?

**Update: I have this in the POM**

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.restlet.gae</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.gwt</artifactId>
      <version>2.2-RC3</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you share the `curl` command you used, so we can see that it matches up with the java listed above?

Comment: I did another test here: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:8888/publicstore?id=null&type=user`

Comment: That one above worked and was able to save into the datastore, the post call from GWT (with Restlet GWT) always fails. However I have another call a get call similar code, and works fine. Furthermore the query parameters are ok and the server gets it, only the Representation entity is null.

Comment: Did you install the GWT extension of Restlet Framework on the server-side? It is necessary to communicate with the Restlet/GWT client code, it doesn't rely on JSON.

Comment: @JeromeLouvel Yes I have this in the POM: org.restlet.ext.gwt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make this call run do the following things:

- add the Json extension (org.restlet.ext.json.jar)  of the framework taken from the GWT edition to your project
- add the following dependency to your GWT module
- then update your code as follow:

  resource.post(new JsonRepresentation(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, jsonObject));

I notice that it works if you send a representation, instead of an object.
The main problem is that when handling an object, the core module does not how to serialize it. In a JVM, we can plug a service that discovers the available converters that automagically convert a bean into a representation, we can't achieve this using GWT.

Having said that, I think you can integrate your client and server code in a easier way, by just using beans. The GWT client code can communicate using the specific GWT serialization format, any other client code using JSON.

Have a look at this code: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/introduction/first-steps/first-application

Comment: I update the framework in order to add a trace in such case. This will help to debug.

Comment: hello, can you also check this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271860/bean-validation-annotation-breaks-reslet-clientproxy